# How resolve redirects issues

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am facing big issue after using cloudflare. I am not adeveloper .I am a simple person. How  I can resolve this issue through htaccess file  ?
My current htaccess file is here

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
RewriteRule ^min/\w+\.(css|js) - [E=cache-control:no-vary]

### marker MOBILE start ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mobile|Android|Silk/|Kindle|BlackBerry|Opera\ Mini|Opera\ Mobi [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=ismobile]
### marker MOBILE end ###

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

### marker WEBP start ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "image/webp" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Page Speed"
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
### marker WEBP end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
### marker BROWSER CACHE start ###
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType application/pdf A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon A2592000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2592000

ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/webp A2592000

ExpiresByType video/ogg A2592000
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A2592000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A2592000
ExpiresByType video/webm A2592000

ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000

ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff A2592000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A2592000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A2592000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A2592000
ExpiresByType font/ttf A2592000
ExpiresByType font/woff A2592000
ExpiresByType font/woff2 A2592000

</IfModule>
### marker BROWSER CACHE end ###

### marker MINIFY start ###
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/min/(\w+)\.(css|js)$
RewriteCond %1/wp-content/cache/$2/$1.$2 -f
RewriteRule min/(\w+)\.(css|js) wp-content/cache/$2/$1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>
### marker MINIFY end ###

## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: So, what are the "redirect issues" you are facing? There doesn't appear to be any external "redirects" in the code you posted? Maybe this is a WordPress issue?

Comment: Sir I recently check my blog through gtmetrix and I found redirects.

Comment: You need to identify what the "problem" actually is (what redirects are you seeing)? So, it seems your site is "working OK", it's just this external tool (gtmetrix) is identifying a "problem" (possibly a redirect chain I would guess - which isn't necessarily a problem to begin with). As I mentioned above, there are no redirects in the code you've posted, so the problem does not appear to be with `.htaccess` and you wouldn't necessarily use `.htaccess` to solve this. (It's looking more like a WordPress issue?)

Comment: The other issue here is that Stack Exchange (predominantly StackOverflow and ProWebmasters) are littered with questions on how to fix _problems_ that "gtmetrix" has supposedly highlighted  - which aren't actually problems to begin with.

Comment: Sir the issue is redirects http to https and https to https://www

Comment: As gtmetrix test results said 'Avoid landing page redirects for the following chain of redirected URLs.

http://medicinesofbody.com/
https://medicinesofbody.com/
https://www.medicinesofbody.com/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the issue is redirects `http` to `https` and `https` to `https://www`

This would seem to be caused by code within WordPress itself - since the `.htaccess` code you posted does not contain any redirects of this nature.

However, you can "fix"<sup>***1**</sup> this in `.htaccess` by redirecting directly to the canonical URL (ie. `https://www`), which naturally occurs *before* WordPress starts up.

For example, at the very top of your `.htaccess` file add the following (where `example.com` is your domain name):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

This redirects any request that is not already HTTPS or is not already for www to HTTPS + www.

Note, first test this with a 302 (temporary) redirect before changing this to a 301 (permanent) redirect in order to avoid any potential caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

---

<sup>***1**</sup> Note that this isn't necessarily a problem that needs fixing. Search engines (and users for that matter) handle short redirect chains like this without any problem. It is an edge case, to catch users that manually type the URL in to the browser or where 3rd parties have perhaps linked to the wrong/old URL in the past. Note that if you had any intention to get on the [HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.org/) then a short redirect chain like this is actually required, since you must redirect to HTTPS on the same host, *before* redirecting to www ("gtmetrix" would therefore be *wrong* in this case).

Comment: Thank you sir. How i can change those codes directly in the WordPress  ?

Comment: I'm not sure - there isn't necessarily one place that would need changing since it could be controlled by a plugin. And since there is a redirect "chain" (ie. multiple redirects) this is quite likely being done in different places in the WordPress code.